# Checkbox left hand navigation drill down

Tags: navigation, forms

Does anyone have an idea on how I can go about creating this navigation? I have a section of a website that has subwords of a top vocabulary word that I would like to show in a left hand menu in order to drill down to the content with checkboxes.

[]Topic 1 ---> if checked show excerpts of all articles with this topic in the content area.
[]Topic 2 ---> if checked show these articles... 

[]etc...

The user could check 1 or all of the topics and get the articles.

Sort of like: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/checkboxes-in-the-category-list

Thanks for any direction, help or the like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help others out here! This is called Faceted Search. After looking around and around online, I found it. There are a lot of posts about it. Drupal 7 uses [Facet API](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi) to do this. However, it is still not extremely straight fwd...